# Is my bootloader or something stored on my new bootable flash drive?

Tags: boot, usb, bootloader, reboot, drive

I have Windows 10, and an SSD and HDD. Win10 is on my SSD, HDD is nothing but storage for windows, except there's also a small 16GB Ubuntu partition on it. Before recently, if I restarted, It would give me a linux looking boot options screen where I could pick Win Bootloader, or Ubuntu.

Then I created a bootable USB installation drive to make new bootable Ubuntu flash drives with persistent storage. Process went like this. Make installation media, plug in installation media, restart, choose to boot from installation media. Then, from within that installation media OS, I made a bootable Ubuntu flash drive with persistent storage (128GB flash drive). Restart, unplug installation media, plug in new bootable OS drive, boot to it.

Everything works perfectly all the time, EXCEPT, if I restart my system withOUT the new 128GB bootable flash drive plugged in, I get the 'Black Screen of Death', just a black terminal with limited commands available. Every time. /reboot works on that screen, but it comes right back to that screen.

IF I plug in that 128Gb flash drive, then restart, THEN I get all the boot options I normally get, including the flash drive, Win bootloader, and the Ubuntu partition on my HDD. But without the 128GB flash drive plugged in, I can't restart and subsequently successfully boot to any of my OSs.

How can I fix this issue? I know some of my terminology is a lil wrong here and there, and I might not have given all the info needed to solve this, so if you feel I should include any more info, just let me know and I'll include anything asked for.

Thank you very much for any assistance!

Comment: See launchpad bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  Several workarounds are in the bug comments, and do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug (upper left corner).

Comment: While answer below by Emre will let you reinstall grub, it may be worthwhile to see details. Do you only have grub, but not an install on sdb internal drive? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your grub (Linux bootloader) to see if that solves your issue. In order to do that, follow these commands on a Live environment.

*Note:`/dev/sda` might be `/dev/nvme0np1`(or something similar) on your situation. Check with `lsblk` to list your volumes.*

1. Mount your Ubuntu installed on the HDD

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt (root partition)
sudo mount /dev/sdaY /mnt/boot (required if separate boot partition)
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

2. Change your main working directory to the mounted Ubuntu

```
sudo chroot /mnt/
```

3. After you've changed your main working directory to Ubuntu installed on HDD, update grub via

```
update-grub
```